# android:checkableBehavior="single" doesn't work on grouped submenu

Tags: android, menu, submenu

I write the following menu XML to create 2 groups submenu, I want items within each group to be single checkable but not all/multi checkable, don't know why the menu comes out always as "all/multi" checkable:

```
<item android:title="Color">
    <menu>
        <group android:id="@+id/ColorMenuGroup" android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/Black"
                android:title="@string/black" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/Blue"
                android:title="@string/blue" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/Red"
                android:title="@string/red" />
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>

<item android:title="Width">
    <menu>
        <group android:id="@+id/WidthMenuGroup" android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/Width1"
                android:title="@string/_1"
            <item
                android:id="@+id/Width3"
                android:title="@string/_3"
            <item
                android:id="@+id/Width5"
                android:title="@string/_5"
                </group>
    </menu>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue.

My work around is to uncheck the previous item manually.

```
OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        previousDrawerItem!!.isChecked = false
        return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
```